# Removing space between widget and horizontal panel

Tags: gwt, border-spacing

[image: GUI element]

The inner rectangle you can see is a horizontal panel. and I have added 3 buttons into it. I want all these buttons to be places at bottom - most part of horizontal panel. I tried following line of code

```
margin-bottom: 0px;
```

but it has no effect on the buttons. Can anybody suggest me anything in regards of this?

Comment: An alternative I can suggest to work it out is, instead of horizontal panel use Absolute panel and add widget using method addWidget(Widget widget,int Left,int Top);

Comment: Thanks I was missing this alternative but now I can use this also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you need to do

1) `horizontalPanel.setSpacing(0);` Reference : [setSpacing](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CellPanel.html#setSpacing%28int%29)

2) `horizontalPanle.setCellVerticalAlignment(widget, HasVerticalAlignment.Align_Bottom);` Refernce : [setCellVerticalAlignment](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CellPanel.html#setCellVerticalAlignment%28com.google.gwt.user.client.Element,%20com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasVerticalAlignment.VerticalAlignmentConstant%29)

Comment: I was setting SetSpaing(10) but later I commented it. I thought if I am not setting any value it is default by 0. But by using horizontalPanel.setSpacing(0); I am able to achieve my desired output.